# How to set OnTouchListener for dynamically created views?

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener

I have two layouts, one `LinearLayout` and one `RelativeLayout`. In the `LinearLayout` I have 10 images. When I click one image, it is added to the `RelativeLayout`. Similar event is given for all 10 images. In the `RelativeLayout`, I have set a `OnTouchListener` to the `ImageView` added from the `LinearLayout`. But my problem is,  `onTouch` only works for the `ImageView` which is recently added but when I try to touch previously added images, it doesn't work. I want to add listener for all images added in the relative layout.

Below is what I have tried so far:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
           image[i] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            try{
               // int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier(data[i], null, getPackageName());
                image[i].setImageResource(data[i]);

            }catch(Exception e){
                int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("nia", "drawable", "package");
                image[i].setImageResource(imgID);
            }         
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams LEye = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    100 , 70);
            LEye.leftMargin=20;
            image[i].setLayoutParams(LEye);
            shapeImageContainer.addView(image[i]); //shapeImageContainer is the Linear Layout
           final int c=i;
            image[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    //addContentView( addIcon(), new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
                    Toast.makeText(NewProject.this, "Position "+c, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    rootView.addView(addIcon(c)); //rootView is the Relative layout

                }
            });

            //image[i].setOnTouchListener(MyOnTouchListener);

        }


private ImageView addIcon(int c){
        item = new ImageView(this);
        item.setImageResource(data[c]);
        item.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 60 );
        if( mIconIdCounter != 1 ){
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,c-1);
        }
        item.setLayoutParams( params );
        item.setId( mIconIdCounter );
        ++mIconIdCounter;
        item.setOnTouchListener(MyOnTouchListener);
        return item;
    }

    OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          scroll.setEnabled(false);
//          horizontal.setEnabled(false);

//          scroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//          horizontal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) item.getLayoutParams();
                switch(event.getActionMasked())
                {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        scroll.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        horizontal.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                        //right margin
                        if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                            x_cord = windowwidth-10;
                        }

                        // left margin original
                        if (x_cord <68) {
                            x_cord = 68;
                        }
                        // left margin original
                        if (y_cord <68) {
                            y_cord = 68;
                        }
                        if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                            y_cord = windowheight-10;
                        }

                       // tv.setText(String.valueOf(y_cord));
                        layoutParams2.leftMargin = x_cord -60;
                        layoutParams2.topMargin = y_cord -65;
                        item.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            return true;
        }

    };
```

Comment: Post your layout XML file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But my problem is, onTouch only works for the imageview which is
>   recently added but when I try to touch previously added images,it
>   doesn't work.

That's because in the `OnTouchListener` you use the `item` field to do your work(which will always point to the last `ImageView` added as you wrote the code) instead of using the `View` for which the listener is called. Try something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  layoutParams2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
// rest of the onTouch callback...
v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
```